# How to change the dotnet SDK version for the particular build?

Tags: .net-core, build

I have both dotnet SDK 6 (6.0.101) and 5 (5.0.406) installed. So when I build the code SDK 6 is used. I would like to check if my changes would build cleanly when SDK 5 is used. I do not want to uninstall SDK 6. Is it possible to instruct the particular command line build to use SDK 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stupid me, it is really simple and explained here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version

Creating global.json with the following content solved my issue:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "5.0.406"
  }
}
```